# Laplace transforms please help

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I really need help to find to Laplace transforms of $f(x)=x+e^{-x}$, and $g(x)=xe^x$. I'm having big troubles on the calculations. Thanks.

Comment: split f up into two integrals.  recognize g as an integration by parts problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $F(s)=\int_0^{\infty}{f(t)e^{-st}dt}=\int_0^{\infty}{(t+e^{-t})e^{-st}dt}=\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-st}dt}+\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-t}e^{-st}dt}=\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-st}dt}+\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-t(s+1)}dt}$
And $G(s)=\int_0^{\infty}{te^{t}e^{-st}dt}=\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-t(s-1)}dt}$

Use integration by parts for both.

Also remember since we have improper integrals we will end up with limits that are undefined, so we need L'hopital's rule to solve them (the exponential always wins!....).

EDIT:
First I'll do $\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-st}dt}$ (and then we can do the same thing for $s+1$).
Let
$$u=t\to{du}=dt,$$
$$dv=e^{-st}dt\to{v}=\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}$$
So using integration by parts,
$$\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-st}dt}=\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_0^b{te^{-st}dt}=\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{te^{-st}}{-s}|_0^b-\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{1}{-s}\int_0^b{e^{-st}dt}$$
$$=\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{t}{-se^{st}}|_0^b-\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{(-s)^2}|_0^b=\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\frac{b}{-se^{sb}}-\frac{0}{s}\right)-\lim_{b\to \infty}\left({\frac{1}{s^2e^{sb}}}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{b}{se^{sb}}-0-0+\frac{1}{s^2}$$
Because $$\lim_{b\to \infty}{\frac{b}{-se^{sb}}}=\frac{\infty}{\infty},$$
We can use L'Hopital's rule to get it in the form $$\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{1}{s^2e^{st}}=0$$
Finally we can say that $$\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-st}dt}=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
Since $s$ is just a constant when we integrate with respect to $t$, we can also say that
$$\int_0^{\infty}{te^{-(s-1)t}dt}=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}$$

Thus we can see that 
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s+1}$$
$$G(s)=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}.$$

Comment: I can't develop this net gears and use limits to get to the solutions... :( cn you help me out???? I'd like to use this resolution instead the other one..

Comment: give me a bit and I'll work it out for you.

Comment: Check your above... I'm not sure what "net gears" is though, but I figured you are doing first proofs, so the integration needed to be carried out before doing Laplace Transforms by table.

Comment: Thanks Ill checo it out now!

Comment: Just finished the exercise! Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

We use the properties of Laplace transformation, you can find them here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

$\displaystyle{ \bullet \quad \mathcal{L} \{x \} = \int_{0}^{+ \infty} e^{-st}t dt = \lim_{a \to + \infty}  - \frac{e^{-st}}{s^2} (st+1) \big|_0^a = \cdots = \frac{1}{s^2} }$

$\displaystyle { \bullet \quad \mathcal{ L} \{ e^x \} = \int_{0}^{+ \infty} e^{-st} e^t dt=  \lim_{ a \to + \infty} \frac{ e^{(1-s)t}}{1-s} |_0^a = \frac{1}{s-1} }$

Using the properties now we get:

$\displaystyle{ \bullet \quad \mathcal{L} \{f \} = \mathcal{ L} \{x+e^{-x} \} =\mathcal{L} \{x\} +\mathcal{L} \{e^{-x} \cdot 1 \} = \frac{1}{s^2} + F(s+1) = \frac{1}{s^2} + \frac{1}{s+1} }$ ,where $\displaystyle{ F(s)= \mathcal{L} \{1\} }$

$\displaystyle{ \bullet \mathcal{ L} \{xe^x \} = F(s-1) =\frac{1}{(s-1)^2} }$, where we used the property that $\displaystyle{ \mathcal{L} \{ e^{at} f(t) \} = F(s-a) ; F(s)= \mathcal{L} \{f\} }$. In your case is$\displaystyle{ F(s)=\mathcal{L} \{t\} } $